# Which is better Math.random() or UIDUtil.createUID()

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I need to generate a random number/string to append to a URL to prevent caching of an image.

Which would be better:

`Math.random()` or `UIDUtil.createUID()`

I know it more than likely will come down to user preference, but I'd like to get everyone's opinion as to which one to use and why.

Comment: Really it's nothing to do with "user preference", but maybe developer preference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cachebuster that I've always seen used is:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Math.random() of course has the possibility of not generating a unique url (however unlikely). Other than that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I was just in the middle of writing this exact answer ;)

Comment: Using Math.random() or new Date().getTime() are probably preferred over UIDUtil.createUID() b/c the former are both *native* Flash Player classes (executing at c-like speed). While UIDUtil is a Flex class written in Actionscript (executing at something slower than c-like speed). Granted, this only matters if you're doing it a million times ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I rolled out a version that used UIDUtil.createUID() and counted the number of times that it gets used in a 24 hour period and it was generating over 12 million ID's so I ended up switching over to the new Date().getTime() which I completely forgot about.